# Odoo 15 Scheduler not running automatically or even with clicking Run Manually

Tags: python, cron, scheduler, odoo-15

I have a problem with running a scheduler in Odoo 15.

I have a function python like this for sending messages to chat:

```py
def action_send_notification(self):
    today_date = datetime.today()
    for i in self:
        if i.search([('date_end','<',today_date)]):
            message = "STR has been expired"
            recipient1 = i.employee_id.user_id.partner_id.id
            recipient2 = i.env['res.users'].sudo().search([('name', 'ilike', 'admin')])                              
            channel = i.env['mail.channel'].channel_get([recipient1])
            channel_id = i.env['mail.channel'].browse(channel["id"])
            channel_id.message_post(    
               body=message,
               message_type='comment',
               subtype_xmlid='mail.mt_comment',)
```

For cron XML, here it is:

```xml
<record id="STR_notif_expiration_scheduler" model="ir.cron">
    <field name="name">STR Notif Expiration</field>
    <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root" />
    <field name="interval_number">1</field>
    <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
    <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
    <field name="doall">0</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_hr_str"/>
    <field name="code">model.action_send_notification()</field>
    <field name="priority">5</field>
</record>
```

When I run by clicking Run Manually it's not working.
It's not running automatically as well.

But when I try to run the python function by a custom button, it's working.

My expectation is that the scheduler can run by Run Manually and even automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using @api.model decorator on the method.also add
`<field name="state">code</field>`
. It should work

Comment: thanks for your solution but its still not working on me , even when I put @api.model decorator , its show error function() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given